# jQuery if/else statement to change css on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$('#submitbtn').on("click", function() {
    $('.message-box').val();
    var message = $(".message-box").val();
    $('#visible-comment').html(message);
    $('.message-box').hide();
  return false;
});
```

I want the above code in an if/else condition that if the value of .message-box is an empty string to change the border color of .message-box to red.

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

I've tried the following, which changes the border red, but doesn't fire the rest of the code.

```
    $('#submitbtn').on("click", function() {

  if ($(".message-box").val("")) {
    $(".message-box").css("border","2px solid red");
  } else {

    $('.message-box').val();
    var message = $(".message-box").val();
    $('#visible-comment').html(message);
    $('.message-box').hide();
  return false;
  }
});
```

sample here : https://jsfiddle.net/wf69c7uu/2/

Comment: Just change `if ($(".message-box").val() === '')`

Comment: When you give an argument to `.val()` it **sets**  the value, it doesn't compare it.

Comment: To get the value you call `.val()` with no argument.

Comment: Your condition is not proper Update fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/wf69c7uu/3/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/val/#val

Comment: Thank you so much..

Comment: You should check for spaces as an empty value as well, probably. Try this one over here, forked from your example: https://jsfiddle.net/mfbftjwe/1/

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to check for your conditions, and then simply add or remove the class based on the evaluation of the expression.

[Here is a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wf69c7uu/5/)

The code would look like the following:

```
$('#submitbtn').on("click", function() {
    $('.message-box').val();
    var message = $(".message-box").val();
    if (message === '') {
        $('.message-box').addClass("invalid");
    }
    else {
      $('.message-box').removeClass("invalid");
      $('#visible-comment').html(message);
      $('.message-box').hide();
    }
  return false;
});
```

Or, optionally, you can check the input in "real-time" as the user types like so:

```
$('#submitbtn').on("click", function() {
    $('.message-box').val();
    var message = $(".message-box").val();
    if (!$(".message-box").hasClass("invalid")) {
      $('#visible-comment').html(message);
      $('.message-box').hide();
    }
  return false;
});

$(".message-box").on("input propertychange", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass("invalid") && $this.val() === '') {
    $this.addClass("invalid");
  }
  else if ($this.hasClass("invalid") && $this.val() !== '') {
    $this.removeClass("invalid");
  }
});
```

Comment: analogs: http://jsfiddle.net/lega911/rvp52f6y/ or http://jsfiddle.net/lega911/uxst8s2n/

Answer (score 0):

Slightly changed the code which you posted on jsfiddle:

- Added an `if else` block.
- Added `$('.message-box').css("border", "4px solid red");` to set the border color of the `textarea` when it's empty.

  ```
  $(function () {
      $('#submitbtn').on("click", function () {
          var message = $(".message-box").val();
          if (message == "") {
              $('.message-box').css("border", "4px solid red");
          }
          else {
              $('#visible-comment').html(message);
              $('.message-box').hide();
              return false;
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

- Add e.preventDefault function so that your POST action will not be triggered.
- Add if/else statement to check if your message box was empty.

```js
$('#submitbtn').on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
        $('.message-box').val();
        var message = $(".message-box").val();
        if(message == ""){
         $(".message-box").css("border","2px solid red");
        }else{
         $('#visible-comment').html(message);
         $('.message-box').hide();
        }
    });
```